# Are popular browser extensions for anonymity as safe as Tor?

Tags: web-browser, proxy, tor, anonymity, browser-extensions

There are many different browser extensions that people use in order to hide their IP addresses and protect their anonymity. Can the reliability of these proxy extensions be considered as being on the same level as that of Tor?

Tor works fairly slow, but it is relatively reliable service. Browser extensions allow more quick surfing. Due to the lightness and quickness during work with all these extensions I feel that it is probably not as safe as Tor and I should not consider it as a reliable service for anonymity. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Tor is not the same as a proxy server. I suggest you read up more on what Tor is and how it works.

Comment: not sure if riffle has a browser extension, but worth checking out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riffle_(anonymity_network)

Comment: Tor is probably on a similar level as using 3 VPNs in a row. Maybe slightly more, because there's the option of bridges (hide from ISP), and you'd be able to use different nodes for new connections. It would, of course, depend on what you need and what your extensions are.

Comment: @Alpha3031 why 3 VPNs?

Comment: Tor itself is not safe enough. I usually run `proxychains firefox` and by default it uses tor proxies which are not secure. I suggest finding some IPs on internet and then use them to connect to deeper web and find proper ones in there.

Comment: @GnP The approximation is based of the fact that Tor [uses 3 nodes per connection by default](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/103/is-it-possible-to-make-the-tor-onion-routing-path-longer). I'll add that It might also be slightly less safe that the VPNs if the VPN servers are machines you can trust, as opposed to Tor nodes, which are volunteer run and might be compromised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. They are different safe than TOR!
Anonymity is complex and there is no "X is better than Y" answer.

If the extension uses a simple unencrypted proxy, for example, everyone between you and the target server can read all your data. The proxy server provider knows your IP and can log everything you do.

If it is a encrypted VPN, between you and the VPN Provider, no one on that path, like your ISP, can read your data. The VPN provider can see all your data, log everything you do and knows your IP.

If you use TOR, the data is encrypted between you and the TOR exit node in multiple layers. The TOR exit node owner (some random person which you can't identify) can read all your data. She doesn't know your IP, but does know everything you send over the connection. There are some malicious exit nodes!

In all cases, everything you do over an unencrypted connection (not https) can be read by someone.

Answer (score -4):

It depends. Browser extension often connect to vpn or proxy server.
But it's known that free vpns are so much slower than paid ones.
So yes they are reliable but they may be slow.